# Git for Windows Blob Compression

Tags: c#, git, zlib

I'm attempting to make a tool which works with a raw git repository created by GIT for Windows. I need to decompress a raw object from the `.git/objects` directory. Here is the object's hex dump:

```
00000000  78 01 2b 29 4a 4d 55 30 36 63 30 34 30 30 33 31  |x.+)JMU06c040031|
00000010  51 c8 4d cc cc d3 2b a9 28 61 e8 a9 8b 4a ab 97  |QÈMÌÌÓ+©(aè©.J«.|
00000020  2e 97 70 ff d7 71 40 c6 f6 b1 8b f0 c2 4d 0a 00  |..pÿ×q@Æö±.ðÂM..|
00000030  33 56 0f 42                                      |3V.B|
```

If I dump this with GIT for Windows, I receive the following contents:

```
$ git cat-file -p 9171a57695205f9d7f03f1d2872b110b0ee538e9
100644 blob 8c7e5a667f1b771847fe88c01c3de34413a1b220    main.txt
```

When I attempt to decompress it using the [DotNetZip library](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip) and also [an online tool](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hexdump()Zlib_Inflate(0,0,'Adaptive',false,false)&input=MDAwMDAwMDAgIDc4IDAxIDJiIDI5IDRhIDRkIDU1IDMwIDM2IDYzIDMwIDM0IDMwIDMwIDMzIDMxICB8eC4rKUpNVTA2YzA0MDAzMXwKMDAwMDAwMTAgIDUxIGM4IDRkIGNjIGNjIGQzIDJiIGE5IDI4IDYxIGU4IGE5IDhiIDRhIGFiIDk3ICB8UchNzMzTK6koYeipLkqrLnwKMDAwMDAwMjAgIDJlIDk3IDcwIGZmIGQ3IDcxIDQwIGM2IGY2IGIxIDhiIGYwIGMyIDRkIDBhIDAwICB8Li5w/9dxQMb2sS7wwk0uLnwKMDAwMDAwMzAgIDMzIDU2IDBmIDQyICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB8M1YuQnw), it does not decompress properly. The output my program produces when trying to decompress is:

```
00000000  74 72 65 65 20 33 36 00 31 30 30 36 34 34 20 6d  |tree 36.100644 m|
00000010  61 69 6e 2e 74 78 74 00 8c 7e 5a 66 7f 1b 77 18  |ain.txt..~Zf..w.|
00000020  47 fe 88 c0 1c 3d e3 44 13 a1 b2 20              |Gþ.À.=ãD.¡² |
```

I understand that `git cat-file` strips off the object header, so that is one difference, but why is the remainder of the object not properly inflated?

The code I used to try to inflate, depends on nuget package "Zlib.Portable.Signed":

```
using Ionic.Zlib;
using System.IO;

namespace TestInflate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var lFrom = File.OpenRead("IN"))
            using (var lInflate = new ZlibStream(lFrom, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var lTo = File.Create("OUT"))
                lInflate.CopyTo(lTo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `tree 36` means you're looking at the *tree* object that *contains* the blob object, rather than at the blob object itself.

Comment: @torec, correct I want the contents of the tree. I am aware I am looking at the tree itself, though perhaps my terminology was not exact.

Comment: OK, well, tree objects are binary objects. For what's *in* them, see, e.g., https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, your decompresser is fine.  The issue is that you're examining the *tree* object that refers to subtrees and blobs.

All objects start with a header giving the object's type, and the overall size in bytes but expressed as an ASCII string.  So `tree 36` indicates that this is a tree, and the tree is 36 bytes long.  That's followed by an ASCII NUL, 0x00, or <kbd>CTRL-@</kbd>.  After that come the tree entries.

Each entry has the form *mode* <kbd>space</kbd> *name* <kbd>CTRL-@</kbd> *hash*.  The hash is *binary*, and always exactly 20 bytes long (at least until Git switches to a new hash; how this will be indicated, and encoded, is not yet decided).  Your *`mode`* is `100644` and your *`name`* is `main.txt`, so you have 6+1+8+1+20 = 36 bytes, which is the length in the header, so that's the entire tree.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was missing. Everywhere I found talked about trees being in the textual format given by `cat-file` and never mentioned they are stored differently on-disk.